# How to collect the activity execution time exercised in the database MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database

How to collect the runtime of various activities held in the database?

example:

```
 INSERT INTO myset (col) VALUES ('a, d, d, s');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.03 sec)

  INSERT INTO myset (col) VALUES ('y, x, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.04 sec)
```

I would like to save this time that it was executed

0.03
0.04
and so on ...

is there any place where it gets saved where I can access later or do I need to collect and save?

I'd like to save this or have access, and then take some analysis.